# Editable Related questions links list for every question on the site

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

It would be nice to add a manually editable editable (and/or automatic) list of "related questions", a "see also" for every question on the site.

These may be questions on related domains, doing same thing on a different platform, ideas that might be helpful for the user to solving differently an alternative problem to the one he is asking about.

In this case, the list would be editable/sortable by higher-ranked veterans, and everyone would be able to suggest a related question to the middle of the list. The end of the list might contain automatically-added related questions, similarly to the list on "ask a question" page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this what Linked Posts already does?

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/new-linked-posts/

Basically just hyperlink posts in comments, questions and answers, and they'll appear in the Linked Posts area on the right sidebar.

They are sorted by votes, so the highest voted links will show up on *both* sides.

Comment: Not exactly what I had in mind, but seems sufficient.